# Conformal maps and elliptic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone please help me with the following complex (?) analysis question? I'm given a triangle $T$ (say with angles $30^{\circ}$, $60^{\circ}$ and $90^{\circ}$) and a conformal map from $T$ onto the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$. How can one extend this $f$ to an elliptic function in $\mathbb{C}$ and what would be the degree of $f$ (the sum of the orders of the poles)?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Schwarz reflection principle?

Comment: How does one compute an explicit form?